# Swift - How to update observed data in a (custom or not) MKAnnotation callout WITHOUT deselecting the annotation

Tags: swift, dynamic, annotations, key-value-observing, callouts

I'm struggling to get KVO updates within a callout already displayed.

My use case: I want to display on an open callout the real time distance between user location and the annotation I add to the map. Annotation does not change its position.

- I add annotations to mapView, using a custom annotation I have defined. No issue here.
- On each annotation selected, the callout displays all the information defined in the custom annotation
- However, the distance is refreshed in the callout ONLY if I unselect the annotation and reselect it

The distance property is declared as @objc dynamic so it can be observed.
I compute the distance each time the user location change. This part works too.

I cannot figure out what I'm missing to have the callout updated without closing and reopening it.

The code I'm using is what is described here by Rob: [Swift -How to Update Data in Custom MKAnnotation Callout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203561/swift-how-to-update-data-in-custom-mkannotation-callout)

So my question: is it possible to change realtime a value (observed) in a notificationView callout ? If yes is KVO the best approach ?
In the link below, how would be implemented the mapView viewFor method ?

Any example would be very helpful.

It's my first post here, so please if I did it wrong, let me know and I will provide more information and details.
But my situation is trivial: the standard callout performs Key-Value Observation (KVO) on title and subtitle. (And the annotation view observes changes to coordinate.). But how to display change of values in the current open callout ? That is the think I do not get.

CustomAnnotation class:

```
class CustomAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    @objc dynamic var title: String?
    @objc dynamic var subtitle: String?
    @objc dynamic var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    @objc dynamic var distance: CLLocationDistance
    var poiColor: String?
    var poiPhone: String?    
    
    init(title: String, subtitle: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, poiColor: String, poiPhone: String, distance: CLLocationDistance) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.poiColor = poiColor
        self.poiPhone = poiPhone
        self.distance = distance
        super.init()
    }
}
```

CustomAnnotationView class:

```
    class CustomAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        displayPriority = .required
        canShowCallout = true
        detailCalloutAccessoryView = createCallOutWithDataFrom(customAnnotation: annotation as? CustomAnnotation)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    deinit {
        removeAnyObservers()
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet {
            removeAnyObservers()
            if let customAnnotation = annotation as? CustomAnnotation {
                updateAndAddObservers(for: customAnnotation)
            }
        }
    }

    private var subtitleObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?
    private var distanceObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

    private let subtitleLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    private let distanceLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
}

private extension CustomAnnotationView {
    func updateAndAddObservers(for customAnnotation: CustomAnnotation) {
        
        subtitleLabel.text = customAnnotation.subtitle
        subtitleObserver = customAnnotation.observe(\.subtitle) { [weak self] customAnnotation, _ in
            self?.subtitleLabel.text = customAnnotation.subtitle
        }
        
        let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        let theLatitude:CLLocationDegrees = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
        let theLongitude:CLLocationDegrees = (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
        // Get pin location
        let pointLocation = CLLocation(latitude: customAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: customAnnotation.coordinate.longitude)
        //Get user location
        let userLocation = CLLocation(latitude: theLatitude, longitude: theLongitude)
        // Return distance en meters
        let distanceFromUser = pointLocation.distance(from: userLocation)
        customAnnotation.distance = distanceFromUser*100
        distanceLabel.text = String(format: "%.03f", customAnnotation.distance)+" cm"
        distanceObserver = customAnnotation.observe(\.distance) { [weak self] customAnnotation, _ in
            self?.distanceLabel.text = "\(customAnnotation.distance) cm"
        }
    }

    func removeAnyObservers() {
        subtitleObserver = nil
        distanceObserver = nil
    }

    func createCallOutWithDataFrom(customAnnotation: CustomAnnotation?) -> UIView {
        
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        view.addSubview(subtitleLabel)
        view.addSubview(distanceLabel)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            subtitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            subtitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            subtitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            subtitleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: distanceLabel.topAnchor),
            distanceLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            distanceLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            distanceLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

        if let customAnnotation = customAnnotation {
            updateAndAddObservers(for: customAnnotation)
        }
return view
    }
}
```

And to finish:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }
    let annotation = annotation as? CustomAnnotation
    
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "CustomAnnotation") as? CustomAnnotationView
    
    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "CustomAnnotation")
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }
    return annotationView
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You would appear to have correctly configured the observers for the `subtitle` and `distance`. The problem is that a change in location is not triggering an update to `distance`. Thus, there is nothing triggering the KVO.

You have an observer for `distance`, which will trigger an update of the label. But you are not changing `distance`. You should remove the `CLLocationManager` code from that routine where you add the observers, and instead create a location manager (not within the annotation view, though) which uses its `delegate` to update all of the annotation distances, e.g.:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.distanceFilter = 5
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}

extension ViewController: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let currentLocation = locations.last(where: { $0.horizontalAccuracy >= 0 }) else { return }

        mapView.annotations
            .compactMap { $0 as? CustomAnnotation }
            .forEach {
                $0.distance = CLLocation(latitude: $0.coordinate.latitude, longitude: $0.coordinate.longitude)
                    .distance(from: currentLocation)
            }
    }
}
```

Obviously, you would remove the `CLLocationManager` code from `updateAndAddObservers`.

Comment: Rob, you just solved my problem and I'm thankful for that ! I just did not understand completely the KVO pattern before you explain crystal clear. So, it works :-) Thank you again.